# Update model one of the properties of List type is null upon submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model, updatemodel

I have Model class "Customer". One of its properties is a collection of object lets say "Order". I want that during edit I can modify the list of orders associated with the selected Customer that I want to update but when I submit the modified customer and modified orders the order object is null. Please help how can I send the modified orders on edit. Here's my code

**Class**

```
  public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
@model MVCTestApp.Models.Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Customer</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        </div>
        @foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
        {
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label(order.OrderName)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Editor(order.OrderName, new { id = order.OrderId })
            </div>
        }
        <p><input type="submit" value="Save" /> </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

**Submitted Edited View**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **`for-loop`** instead of `foreach`:

```
@for (var i=0;i<Model.Orders.Count();i++)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label(Model.Orders[i].OrderName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(m=> Model.Orders[i].OrderName)
    </div>
}
```

The reason for this issue can be easily seen on the rendered html of the `foreach` approach. The names of the elements do not have an index and they **all have the same name**. The model binder cannot infer how to pass it to your controller. Using a `for-loop` you are somewhat forcing (if that's the right term) the markup/html to have an index on your `Orders` objects. Having done that, the model binder can now properly map your inputs to the `Orders` field.

Oh by the way. Now that you are using a `for-loop` you need to verify that your `Orders` collection is not null. But I'm sure you can easily do that.

Comment: Seriously? You're amazing!!! Thanks this solved my issue. By the way. Can you edit your answer? There's error it should be @Html.Label(Model.Orders[i].OrderName) instead of  @Html.Label(Model[i].OrderName). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to get orders in action like this:(check if order_OrderName is the name of the input filed in form, see the source for example with firebug or something)

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, string[] order_OrderName , Customer customer )
{
  //////
}
```